# How can I visualize rviz publish points?

Tags: python, c++, polygon, ros, marker

I want to combine the publish points via ros-rviz by ticking, but I don't know how to do this exactly, which resources should I look at, is there a sample study?

What I want is done on frontier exploration ros wiki, but how can I add it on a different rviz? How can I make this visualization by giving it publish point?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are looking for but it might be **line strip markers** (see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines)). In case this is not what you are looking for please explain in more detail what you need.

Comment: Thanks, that's not what I want. There is a study on the http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration link. In this study, when you mark the publish points on rviz, it connects the dots. I'm working on exactly this method of connecting the dots, but I haven't found how to do it exactly. Do you have such a resource? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMcQRpBpN1s

Comment: Did you manage to do so following my post or do you still need some help with this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to write a node that **constructs a boundary polygon from the points it gets from Rviz** `Publish point` and then **constructs [line strip markers](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines)** from them and **publishes it back to Rviz**. Inside Rviz you will have to add a `Marker` display subscribing to the corresponding topic. For how this can be done have a look at the C++-node **[`explore_client`](https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration/blob/lunar-devel/src/explore_client.cpp)** inside the [`frontier_exploration` package](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration) as well as the Rviz-configuration`turtlebot_exploration.rviz` inside [`turtlebot_samples`](https://github.com/130s/turtlebot_samples).

Alternatively you could also **write a Rviz plugin**  using the same logic. Tutorials for this can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/groovy/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/), in particular have a look at [`PlantFlagTool`](http://docs.ros.org/en/groovy/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/tool_plugin_tutorial.html).